# how to smoothen edge of imshow python

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I smoothen the edge of this plot and add the degree symbol to the color bar label? I'm using `interpolation= 'nearest'`. It's a 21*21 array.

[image]

edited:This is what I got now.
[image: image 2]

```
figs=plt.imshow(data,interpolation = 'bicubic', extent=[-3.15,3.15,-3.15,3.15], vmin=-5.22, vmax=5.22)
```

Comment: don't use `interpolation='nearest'`?

Comment: post any source code?

Comment: is there any way to make the edge 'rounder'? I tried all the interpolation in this [link](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html)

Comment: For the degree-symbol, use Latex with the command `^\circ`

Comment: Not sure if it will work with your data, but you might try `contourf` with the `corner_mask=True` option. See [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_corner_mask.html)